# How to do zoom in/out or increase font size in mysql work bench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to change the font size of text in the SQL script or zoom in/out.

[image]

I couldn't figure out how. Is there a way I can do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the editor, do you see the drop down labeled "100%". Try that to change the font size.

Comment: Unfortunately, for the Windows version, this 100% drop down does not even exist.

Comment: Yes, this answer was specifically for macOS. But you can assign another font in the preferences, which allows to select a font size.

Comment: Selecting the font in preferences does not affect the zoom state. For the Windows version, MySQL Workbench has to be closed and re-opened to reset the zoom state.

Answer (score 8):

On PC/Windows on laptop I hold down the control button and scroll with mouse touch pad. It zooms in at one move of scroll down, and zooms out when scrolling up. It is not very smooth but that is how it works.

Answer (score 5):

**Mac Answer**

Zoom in and zoom out are available in the view menu, as well as their shortcuts.

**PC Answer**

You can change the font, going to

Edit > Preferences... > Appearance > Fonts section

Afterwards restart mysql workbench to finally change the zoom state

Comment: No it is not. For the PC version, under the View menu, you only have Home, Panels, Select Next Main Tab, Select Previous Main Tab.

Comment: Still wrong. Selecting the font in preferences does not affect the zoom state. For the Windows version, MySQL Workbench has to be closed and re-opened to reset the zoom state.

Answer (score 3):

With MySQL Workbench version 8.0.22 running on Windows 10, zoom in/out works with ALT+mouse wheel instead of CTRL+mouse wheel!

As a summary:

- Scroll the sheet up/down: Mouse wheel
- Scroll the sheet right/left: CTRL + Mouse wheel
- Move the sheet in any direction: Click Mouse wheel and move Mouse
- Zoom in/out the sheet: ALT + Mouse wheel

Answer (score 2):

In Windows
Edit -> Preferences-> Fonts & colors

In the resultset grid text box edit the font size.

By default it is in "Tahoma 10", I changed it to "Tahoma 16".
.Click ok.

Close and Restart Mysql workbench and it works perfectly for me. ^_^

Comment: This is the right answer for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

On PC/Windows laptop zoom in and out works similar to phone on touch pad, just pinch in and out with two fingers.

Answer (score 0):

Mac MySQLWorkbench to change the font size:

1. Go to MySQLworkbench
2. Click on to settings
3. Under the General Editor you can see the Font.
4. Change the font size according to the requirement
5. Click Ok and to see the change quit one time from the MySQLworkbench and login again.