# Text resolution and Font size issue in MySQL workbench 8.0 on windows 10

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Texts resolution and Font size is quite low which is putting a lot of strain on my eyes.
I have tried using *Edit->Preferences->fonts and colors* and then changing the font sizes but its not working not even on restart.

I have also tried correcting the resolution by changing the **High DPI Setting** and then overriding the scaling performed by Application. In this case the resolution is increased but font becomes even smaller.

Can anyone tell me how to figure out this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939253/how-to-do-zoom-in-out-or-increase-font-size-in-mysql-work-bench

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do zoom in/out or increase font size in mysql work bench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939253/how-to-do-zoom-in-out-or-increase-font-size-in-mysql-work-bench)

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem of blurried fonts and textures after installing MySQL Workbench 8.0 on my new Windows 10 machine. The following steps worked for me:

**step 1: Fix blurried textures.** Go to the MySQL Workbench installation folder (`Windows start menu`, type in "Workbench" and right click on the icon and select `open file location`). After that, right click "MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE" and select `properties`, switch to tab `Compatibility`and click the button `Change high DPI settings`. In the lower part of this window, under `High DPI scaling behaviour`check the box (i.e. "override high DPI scaling behaviour") and select the scaling being performed by `Application`. Click `OK` to close the window and click on `Apply` and `OK` to save the settings and close the window. (screenshot: [Properties Window of MySQL Workbench: overriding high DPI scaling by Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxRxP.png))

**step 2: increase text size.** In MySQL Workbench, click on `Edit` and `Preferences`. In the navigation bar on the left-hand side of the preferences window, click on 'Appearance' (located under the group 'Modeling'). On the right-hand side, the lower section lists the fonts (and sizes) of the respective objects. In order to change the font type and/or size, click on an element within the column "Font" and click it again (do not double click!). By default, the following two font type/size defintions are set: Tahoma 11 and Tahoma Bold 12. (screenshot: [Workbench Preferences-window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s7nx.png))

**optional: zoom in.** If you still feel unconfortable with the displayed text size, you can - at least in terms ERD models (and maybe some other aspects) - zoom in. Unfortunately, this is not implemented via clicking and holding CTRL and mouse wheel scrolling. Instead you can either use `CTRL` + `+` (or `-` for zooming out) or you can use the magnifier-icons in the "Bird's Eye" pane (usually upper left pane).

Comment: I followed **step 2** to change the text size of MySQL Navbar, Sidebar, etc. in my Windows 10. However, it is not working. I set them all to 20, then 30, but the text size stays the same.